Solana CLI verify-offchain-signature not compatible with message signing implementations?
We have an API that verifies and off-chain signature using the Solana CLI. It runs the following command:
solana verify-offchain-signature #{message} #{signature} --signer #{public_key}

Our test suite generates a signature using the Solana CLI like so:
solana sign-offchain-message #{message} -k #{private_key_path}
=> <SIGNATURE>

And everything works as expected.
Our client application is a Flutter app in which we use the solana package https://pub.dev/packages/solana. The package specifically calls out supporting the following:

Transaction encoding and signing.
Building and signing offline transactions, as well as convenience methods to sign and send the transaction. Also, the ability to listen for a status change on a given signature. The latter can be used to wait for a transaction to be in the confirmed or finalized state.

Our code is essentially:
Future<String> signMessage(User user, String message) async {
    final message = "message";
    final keypair = await Ed25519HDKeyPair.fromMnemonic(user.mnemonic);
    final signature = await keypair.sign(message.codeUnits);

    return signature.toBase58();
}

While there is no errors in the client app, every signature send to our server is considered invalid. We've verified parity between all the inputs and variables.
Is there a known difference in the message signing between these different packages? We're a bit confused on how to proceed here and whether we'll need to invest in developing our own package for handling offchain message signing.

A Solana off-chain message consists of more than just the message bytes, ie "message" in your example. This is to avoid creating a situation where an attacker gets a victim to sign an off-chain message which is actually a valid transaction.
In your test, you'll want to tack on a bit more to your message:
final message = b"\xffsolana offchain" // header
 + 0 // version
 + <32 bytes for domain>
 + 0 // message format
 + 1 // number of signers
 + <32 bytes for the signer pubkey>
 + [7, 0] // message length, encoded as little-endian u16
 + b"message"; // the actual bytes

And that should do it!
You can read more about the spec at https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/examples/sign-offchain-message and the message format at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/docs/src/proposals/off-chain-message-signing.md
